# Functional dependence not preserved in the weak limit

Tags: pr.probability

Let $M$ be a metric space, $f\colon M \to M$ a measurable function, and $(\mu_n)$ a sequence of probability measures on $M$.
Assume $(\mu_n, f_*\mu_n)$ converges weakly to a measure on $M\times M$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$.
I am looking for an example where $\nu$ is *not* a function of $\mu$ - more precisely where there is no function $g\colon M \to M$ such that $\nu = g_*\mu$.

My question is motivated by the following question of Schramm [1] which sounds almost trivial so I'm looking for some easier examples to get some intuition.
It is well-known that the scaling limit of the random walk $(X_n)$ on $\mathbf{Z}^2$ is the Brownian motion and that the scaling limit of the loop-erased random walk $(\mathrm{LE}(X_n))$ is $\mathrm{SLE}_2$. Schramm's question is whether $(X_n,\mathrm{LE}(X_n))$ also has a scaling limit and (more importantly) if so, is it the case the $\mathrm{SLE}_2$ component is a function the Brownian motion component. (Obviously, one cannot hope that the function in the limit is again $\mathrm{LE}$ since the notion of "first loop" is not well-defined for Brownian motions.)

[1] Schramm, Oded. Conformally invariant scaling limits: an overview and a collection of problems. International Congress of Mathematicians. Vol. I, 513–543. European Mathematical Society (EMS), Zürich, 2007

Comment: What is the meaning of the notation $(\mu_n, f_*\mu_n)$? Is it the product measure (of $ \mu_n$ and $f_*\mu_n$) on $M\times M$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=[0,1]$, $f$ is the indicator function of $[0,1/2)$, and $\mu_n=0.5 \delta_{1/2-1/2n}+0.5 \delta_{1/2+1/2n}$. Then $\mu=\delta_{1/2}$ but $\nu$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=[0,1]$ the unit interval.
For every $n\in\mathbb N$ let $a_{n,1},\dots a_{n,n}$ distinct points in $[0,\frac1n]$, chosen such that all $a_{n,k}$ are pairwise different.
Outside the set $A=\{a_{n,k}: n\in\mathbb{N},\ k\le n\}$ let $f$ be the identity.
On $A$ let $f$ be such that $f(a_{n,k})=\frac kn$.
Let $\mu_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\delta(a_{n,k})$.
Then $\mu_n$ converges weakly to the delta measire $\delta(0)$ and $f_*\mu_n$ converges to the Lebesgue measure.